# Match data from two tables in a MySQL database with PHP PDO and extract

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to extract data based on matched values from two tables on MySQL database with PHP loop?

On table_x I have the column ZIPCODE and on table_y I have ZIPCODE and STREETCODE like this:

```
+-----+---------+  +---------+------------+
| id  | zipcode |  | zipcode | streetcode |
+---------------+  +---------+------------+
| 01  | 1234001 |  | 1111001 |     123    |
+---------------+  +---------+------------+
| 02  | 1234002 |  | 1234001 |     456    |
+---------------+  +---------+------------+
table_x            table_y
```

I want to extract each line from table_x with the matching streetcode from table_y but i'm not sure which `join` to use and if I should replace `foreach` with a `while` loop to achieve my goal.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_x ORDER BY id';
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {                
        echo $row['zipcode'] . "<br>";
        // select from other table
    }
```

Eventually, output each line as the zipcode with the streetcode next to it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NATURAL JOIN`, if the associated tables have the identical column name `zipcode` and the columns are of same data type.

```
SELECT *
FROM table_x
NATURAL JOIN table_y
```

Or use `INNER JOIN` on `zipcode`

```
SELECT *
FROM table_x
INNER JOIN table_y
ON table_x.zipcode=table_y.zipcode
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use join query,

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $user, $pass);
//replace table_x, y with your table names
$sql = "SELECT table_x.zipcode, table_y.streetcode
FROM table_x
INNER JOIN table_y ON table_x.zipcode=table_y.zipcode";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```